# ¿Cómo puedo publicar páginas en la web desde github con la extensión .io?

Tags: html5, github

Me encuentro realizando una página en **sublime text** y me gustaría subirla a la web por medio de github con extensión `.iio`

Según un video anteriormente salía una opción *generador de páginas automático*, sin embargo, en la versión actual, no encuentro esta opción.

Agradecería quien tenga conocimiento y me indique.

Comment: Has probado con [github pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Comment: No y no sé exactamente cómo realizarlo

Comment: Te deje el enlace revisalo, ahí hay una guía

Comment: ok, al realizar los pasos, uno de ellos, indica realizar git clone, pero lo estoy realizando desde windows y no me permite realizarlo intente algunos procesos, pero no mepermite realizarlo

Comment: Que error te sale?